# All solutions of $A^2+I=0$ in $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, matrix-equations

> If $A^2 + I = 0$ is a matrix equation, all solutions $A \in M(n,\mathbb{C})$ are similar to
>   $$
> B = \begin{pmatrix} i I_p & 0 \\ 0 & -i I_m \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $m + p = n$.

Perhaps there is a way to use the Jordan canonical form towards a solution? A hint getting started on this path would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: You don't really need Jordan normal form. $A$ has minimum polynomial dividing $x^{2}+1$ (it  could possibly be $x+i$ or $x-i$ if only one of $i,-i$ is an eigenvalue), which has no repeated roots. A complex $n \times n$ matrix is diagonalizable ( ie similar to a diagonal matrix) if and only if its minimum polynomial has no repeated roots. The eigenvalues of $A$ are clear, so you are almost home.

Comment: How did you deduce the minimum polynomial from $A^2+I=0$? Is this a variant of Cayley-Hamilton? I calculated it as $p_A(x) = (i-x)^m (-i-x)^p$ which obviously does have repeated roots.

Comment: What you calculated is the characteristic polynomial. If $p(x)$ is the minimum polynomial for a complex matrix $M$ and $f(x) = 0$ for some polynomial $f(x)$, then $p(x)$ divides $f(x)$. In particular, the minimum polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial by Cayley-Hamilton, but you don't need that here, since you are told that $A$ satisfies $x^{2} + 1$. In fact, I forgot some extreme cases (when $A$ has only one eigenvalue).

Comment: We have that since $A^2+I=0$, $A$ satisfies the equation $p(x)=x^2+1$.  If $A$ satisfies two polynomial equations, then it must also satisfy their GCD, and from that you can prove both that minimal polynomials exist and that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has to divide $x^2+1$.  We are now just using the fact that $x^2+1$ has no repeated roots.

Answer (score 1):

$A^2+I=0 \implies A^2=-I$. therefore the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are all $-1$, because $A^2$ is a diagonal matrix with $-1$s on the diagonal.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Note that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$, which is $-1$. Hence $\lambda = \pm i$. Thus $A$ has the same eigenvalues as a matrix of the form $B$ (which is diagonal, so has it's  eigenvalues along the diagonal).

Therefore the Jordan canonical form of $A$ will be the same as a matrix of the form $B$ with appropriate $m$ and $n$, and hence $A$ will be similar to a matrix of the form $B$ as they have the same Jordan Canonical form.

Comment: It is not true in general that matrices are similar if and only if they have the same eigenvalues, even if multiplicities match. Eg $I_{2}$ and $\left(\begin{array}{clcr} 1 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ have the same eigenvalues, but are not similar.

Comment: Shouldn't we mention that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$? I believe the diagonalizability of $A$ is why there are no $1$'s on the super-diagonal over the Jordan canonical form.

Comment: In practice, we should be able to deduce the "appropriate" $m$ and $n$ from the characteristic polynomial of $A$, right?

Comment: Of course, when the matrix is diagonalizable, the Jordan form should be diagonal as well. The Jordan form is only a generalization, and as the other answer (which is better) shows, I need not have gone through this  whole problem. As for $m$ and $n$, they will come from the characteristic polynomial of $A$ as you say.